# .add(true) what does a "true" parameter/argument mean

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have just started learning C# and use Visual Studio to write programs. After a lot of searching via internet and my C# book...and asking other experienced programmers...nothing to answer the following question:  What does the parameter/argument "true" in the `add()` method mean in the following lines of code:

```
var excel = new microsoft.office.interop.excel.application();
var workbook = excel.workbooks.add(true**);
```

the `add()` argument usually has nothing in the parenthesis or maybe 1 or 2 to indicate the number of workbooks to open...but "true"? Thanks

Comment: excel interop is a horrible place to start learning

Comment: Well [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx) are the docs, though `add` is in Pascal case. Not sure why yours isn't

Comment: Yeah, it says add(object Template) and it takes an enumeration not a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for the C# VSTO `Workbooks.Add(...)`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx and here is the documentation for the VBA version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-add-method-excel

Office's COM automation APIs for VSTO definitely need some work for C# *ergonomics*. The problem is that the method accepts a COM `Variant` value (`System.Object` in .NET) argument value, which means **it will accept anything you throw at it** and handle it internally without any compile-time type safety. This is a poor API design, instead it should have typed overloads instead ("overloads" are different methods/functions with the same name, but strongly-typed parameters). But there's no point me complaining about it now :D

Further confounding things, the conversion from your `Boolean` `true` value to a COM `Variant` object is done entirely behind-the-scenes. But first, let's consider the documented, valid argument values:

> Optional Object. Determines how the new workbook is created. If this argument is a string specifying the name of an existing Microsoft Excel file, the new workbook is created with the specified file as a template. If this argument is a constant, the new workbook contains a single sheet of the specified type. Can be one of the following XlWBATemplate constants: xlWBATChart, xlWBATExcel4IntlMacroSheet, xlWBATExcel4MacroSheet, or xlWBATWorksheet. If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook with a number of blank sheets (the number of sheets is set by the SheetsInNewWorkbook property).

...that's a lot to consider!

We can derive what the overloads would be and then document them separately:

- `workbook.Add()` - As the parameter is optional, it means you can call it without any arguments. The effect is creating a new workbook with a number of blank sheets (where the number comes from `SheetsInNewWorkbook`).
- `workbook.Add( String templateFileName )` - If the argument is a string, then it's treated as a filename to a template file to use. Obviously this is not marshalable to a `Boolean` value so this is not happening in your case.
- `workbook.Add( Int32 constant )` - The documentation uses the term "constant" which I believe really means an `Int32` value. It only accepts the values from `XlWBATemplate` which are defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlwbatemplate-enumeration-excel - those values are `-4109`, `4`, `3` and `-4167`.

The documentation does not say what happens if the argument value is none of those. The fact it seems to work in your case suggests the value passed as a COM `Variant` containing the bool and it is simply ignored. I don't believe the runtime would marshal the `Boolean` to an `Int32`, given `Variant` supports boolean values, and even if it were marshaled to an `Int32` then you'd likely get an argument error as `1` is not defined in `XlWBATemplate`.

Solution: Change `Workbooks.Add( true )` to just `Workbooks.Add()` and see if there's any change in behaviour. If not, then keep the change; otherwise then you've encountered some undocumented behaviour in the Excel COM API and you should document this in a code-comment (and let us know too!)

Comment: I think they are ditching the c# interop and moving to js approach. So chances are interop will stay that way forever.

Comment: @Steve Office's JavaScript API is not meant for Office Automation, it's meant for offering various "services" via user-interface, while there is a lot of overlap in functionality there's no sign that the COM API will be ditched at all. The C# interop API is just a thin wrapper and generated by an automated program anyway.

Comment: @Steve And Microsoft loves TypeScript!

Comment: @Dai   Hey Dai...Thanks! for your assistance with add().  I'll try out your suggestions.

Comment: @Dai   just replaced add(true) with just add()....and the run results of the program didn't appear to be affected at all.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great answer to a seemingly simple question